# Moving Side bar from left to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have this sidebar which is initially placed on the left to the right side on desktop and bigger screens. is it possible that this sidebar moves to the top from the bottom in tablet and smaller screen? 
like when I clicked on the sidebar in desktop or bigger screens it navigates from left to right, what I want is that when I clicked on the sidebar in tablet or smaller it should expand from top to bottom
This is what I have so far.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "40%";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "40%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 48px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 48px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try tihs out for the solution, let me know if you need more explanation

```js
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");

function openNav() {
  if (!x.matches) {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.height = "60%";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginTop = "50%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "40%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "40%";
  }
}

function closeNav() {
  if (!x.matches) {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginTop = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
  }

}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 36px;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-top .5s;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 48px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    height: 48px;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. this is exactly what I want but only on tablets or smaller screens. 
the default behaviour is fine for desktop and bigger screens

Comment: alright, I have implemented this. but the function is not working in tablet mode. because the default behavior function is still applying. is there any way that there is one function that handles both bigger and smaller screen transitions?

like when I click on the desktop it expands from left to right and in a smaller screen, it expands from top  to bottom by getting instructions from one function

Comment: I have updated the answer for both screens, try now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` queries to determine screen size, and then style it accordingly. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) is a simple explanation from W3schools, then instead of transitioning from the left, you can do it from the top.